# Align buttons in bottom of div

Tags: css, position

I need to do the same of the snnipet, but without height in `.footer`

```css
.footer {
  background: blue;
  width: 1200px;
  height: 250px; //I NEED TO CHANGE THIS
}

.footer .container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.footer .container .col-25 {
  width: 25%;
  float: left;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0 30px;
}

.footer .container .col-25 .footer-col {
  color: #fff;
  height: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}

.footer .container .col-25 .footer-col h2 {
  font-size: 18px;
}

.footer .container .col-25 .footer-col input[type="button"] {
  font-size: 16px;
  color: #3da6cc;
  background: #fff;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 100%;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 3px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 10px;
}

.footer .container .col-25 .footer-col.present .text-centered-y {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}

.footer .container .col-25 .footer-col.present .text-centered-y h1 {
  font-style: italic;
}

.footer .container .col-25 .footer-col.present .text-centered-y h1 span {
  color: #29738e;
}

.footer .container .col-25 .footer-col.present .text-centered-y h3 {
  font-weight: lighter;
}
```

```html
<div class="footer">
   <div class="container">
    <div class="col-25">
     <div class="footer-col">
      <h2>Lorem Ipsum</h2>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud...</p>
      <input type="button" value="Lorem Ipsum" />
     </div>
    </div>
        <div class="col-25">
     <div class="footer-col">
      <h2>Lorem Ipsum</h2>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud...</p>
      <input type="button" value="Lorem Ipsum" />
     </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-25">
     <div class="footer-col">
      <h2>Lorem Ipsum</h2>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud...</p>
      <input type="button" value="Lorem Ipsum" />
     </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-25">
     <div class="footer-col">
      <h2>Lorem Ipsum</h2>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
      <input type="button" value="Lorem Ipsum" />
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: post a fiddle, so it would be easier

Comment: Do you intend to call your class `buttom` rather than `button` ?

Comment: I improved the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the code. Even you don't need to set height. Or you can change too. Or You can extend paragraph/content

```css
.footer {
  background: blue;
  width: 1200px;
}

.footer .container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: flex;
}

.footer .container .col-25 {
  width: 25%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 0 30px;
  padding-bottom: 50px;
}

.footer .container .col-25 .footer-col {
  color: #fff;
  height: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}

.footer .container .col-25 .footer-col h2 {
  font-size: 18px;
}

.footer .container .col-25 .footer-col input[type="button"] {
  font-size: 16px;
  color: #3da6cc;
  background: #fff;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 100%;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 3px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
}

.footer .container .col-25 .footer-col.present .text-centered-y {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}

.footer .container .col-25 .footer-col.present .text-centered-y h1 {
  font-style: italic;
}

.footer .container .col-25 .footer-col.present .text-centered-y h1 span {
  color: #29738e;
}

.footer .container .col-25 .footer-col.present .text-centered-y h3 {
  font-weight: lighter;
}
```

```html
<div class="footer">
   <div class="container">
    <div class="col-25">
     <div class="footer-col">
      <h2>Lorem Ipsum</h2>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud...</p><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud...</p><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud...</p><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud...</p><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud...</p><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud...</p><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud...</p>
      <input type="button" value="Lorem Ipsum" />
     </div>
    </div>
        <div class="col-25">
     <div class="footer-col">
      <h2>Lorem Ipsum</h2>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud...</p>
      <input type="button" value="Lorem Ipsum" />
     </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-25">
     <div class="footer-col">
      <h2>Lorem Ipsum</h2>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud...</p>
      <input type="button" value="Lorem Ipsum" />
     </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-25">
     <div class="footer-col">
      <h2>Lorem Ipsum</h2>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
      <input type="button" value="Lorem Ipsum" />
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Happy Coding Mate